# RStudio not started

Tags: r, rstudio

My R studio wasn't starting. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling R. Still get the following error code:

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.06.1+524 "Mountain Hydrangea " (547dcf86, 2023-07-07) for windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.06.1+524 Chrome/110.0.5481.208 Electron/23.3.0 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 3221225477.

Error output:

```
[17308:17836:20230712,180848.929:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFi,le: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-Asus.log*

Please help. Thank you

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both R environment and RStudio. But it didn't work. I have Windows 64-bit

Comment: Hi Raadhika. Welcome to StackOverflow! This might help: https://community.rstudio.com/t/special-character-in-file-name-windows-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/142668