# R session startup

Tags: r, rstudio, startup

R session startup gives an error. I tried reinstalling both R and Rstudio several times but this didn't work. R itself does work. Does anyone have a suggestion to fix this error? thank you so much in advance.

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.09.1+494 "Desert Sunflower " (cd7011dc, 2023-10-16) for windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.09.1+494 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 3221225477.

Error output:

```
[No errors emitted]
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*C:/Users/avancaesbroeck/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-avancaesbroeck.log*

```
2023-11-08T12:43:10.838417Z [rsession-avancaesbroeck] ERROR system error 10053 (De software op uw hostcomputer heeft een verbinding verbroken) [request-uri: /graphics/3d4d6646-ac49-4ef5-a39b-7cb66b808a17.png]; OCCURRED AT void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-desert-sunflower\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:156; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-desert-sunflower\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:161
2023-11-08T16:09:54.604775Z [rsession-avancaesbroeck] WARNING Invalid values found in C:/Users/avancaesbroeck/AppData/Local/RStudio/rstudio-desktop.json: /save_plot_as_pdf_options/width, /save_plot_as_pdf_options/height; LOGGED FROM: class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::session::prefs::PrefLayer::loadPrefsFromFile(const class rstudio::core::FilePath &,const class rstudio::core::FilePath &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-desert-sunflower\src\cpp\session\prefs\PrefLayer.cpp:166
2023-11-08T16:09:54.604775Z [rsession-avancaesbroeck] WARNING Invalid values found in C:/Users/avancaesbroeck/AppData/Local/RStudio/rstudio-desktop.json: /save_plot_as_pdf_options/width, /save_plot_as_pdf_options/height; LOGGED FROM: class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::session::prefs::PrefLayer::loadPrefsFromFile(const class rstudio::core::FilePath &,const class rstudio::core::FilePath &) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide-os-windows\rel-desert-sunflower\src\cpp\session\prefs\PrefLayer.cpp:166
```

Comment: This question with the same error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76675003/rstudio-not-started) points to this suggestion (https://community.rstudio.com/t/special-character-in-file-name-windows-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/142668), which might come up if one of the directories you're using has special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I just find my local folder of Rstudio and delete it.
It should be under
**(User/your name/AppData/Local/Rstudio)** just delete the folder name Rstudio, that will do it

For me it works. hopefully it might help you as well.